# calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}}{n}=0$?

I can't use $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}\approx \log n$

I've tried to use the following: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}$? but the numbers of items I add goes towards $\infty$ so that doesn't help.

Comment: There's a very nice general theorem that if $\;\lim a_n=L\;$ , then also $$\lim\frac{a_1+\ldots +a_n}n=L$$

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem The result is pretty trivial afterwards.

Comment: You can bound the sum in numerator by comparing it against corresponding integral: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k} \le 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \int_{k-1}^k \frac{dx}{x} = 1 + \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x} = 1 + \log n$$

Answer (score 3):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ H_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\leq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}1\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} \leq \sqrt{n\,\zeta(2)}$$
hence the limit is trivially zero.

Answer (score 0):

Bound the limit by for  all positive epsilon

$0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{N_0}}{n} + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=N_0}^n\frac{1}{n}}{n} \\\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=N_0}^n\frac{1}{n}}{n}\leq\frac{n\frac{1}{N_0}}{n} < \varepsilon$

That is we need $N_0=\lceil1/\varepsilon\rceil$